# Upgrade to 14.04 LTS from 15.04

Tags: upgrade

On the next iteration of the 14.04 LTS (14.04.3), Will I be able to upgrade to it from 15.04 or am I stuck on the monthly track? Specifically, Can I get off the rolling release track?

Comment: What do you call "rolling release track"?

Comment: Ubuntu is not a Rolling Release distro, and to upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04 you'll have to upgrade to 14.10 first.

Comment: @xangua The title reads upgrade **TO** 14.04 LTS **FROM** 15.04, You have that backwards. I think what they mean is to jump from 15.04 to 14.04.3. The "Rolling Release" is 15.04 in this term as canonical/Ubuntu releases every 6 months (.04 and .10) whereas LTS is LongTermSupport. Only speculation though.